# SQL Server CE slow at reading (36 seconds for 1000 rows?)

Tags: c#, vb.net, sql-server-ce, local-database

I have a table `PartNumbers` with 10 columns with mixed data types and just over 100,000 rows.

Here is my test:

I've put an index on the ID column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IndexName ON [PartNumbers] (ID)
```

I get a list of 1000 randomly selected ID's (`Random_ID_List`) and loop through each ID to fetch the description from the table:

```
 Dim Stop_Watch As New Stopwatch
  Stop_Watch.Start()

  Dim Results As New List(Of String)
  LocalDB.SQLCe_Connection.Open()
  For Each ID As Integer In Random_ID_List
   Dim sqlcmd = LocalDB.SQLCe_Connection.CreateCommand()
   sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Description FROM PartNumbers WHERE ID = " & ID
   Results.Add(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar)
  Next
  LocalDB.SQLCe_Connection.Close()

  Stop_Watch.Stop()
  Dim Result_Time As Long = Stop_Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

My result is:

- Result_Time = 36283 ms (**36 seconds**)

Is this normal?

Comment: 36ms per query. Not ridiculous. Try using prepared statements, and/or reducing number of queries via `in` instead of `=`.

Comment: Try `SELECT Id, Description FRO PartNumbers WHERE ID IN (... list of IDs here ...)` You are currently doing an index seek 1000 times.

Comment: @EricJ. this brings it down to 2377 ms, but this still seems slow to me... or is this normal?

Comment: using the same query on the SQL server database i get 30ms

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you use a parameterized query? `sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Description FROM PartNumbers WHERE ID = @Param";` `sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", ID);` I know that in SQL Server that can make a big difference.

Comment: @JonathanAllen that made a massive difference, from 36 seconds to 4059ms (4 seconds) thanks

Comment: Wow. I was expecting it to improve it a little, but nothing like that.

Comment: My 2 cents. Create command and open connection *outside* the `for` loop. In the loop only change parameter value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parameterized query.

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = "SELECT Description FROM PartNumbers WHERE ID = @Param";
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param", ID);
```

I don't know the details for this database, but for other databases you can spend more time parsing the SQL and generating the execution plan than actually running the query.